# I have two list and i want to filter a list on the basis of id present in other list in groovy or java

Tags: java, groovy, java-stream

1st List ->

```
 List<Stat> stats = statService.loadAllStatsByCompanyAndDateStatsFetched(company.uuid, sDate, eDate)
```

2nd List ->

```
Page<Asset> assets = assetService.fetchAllAssetByAssetUuids(assetUuids, pageable)
List<Asset> assetList = asset.getContent()
```

Stat has a variable **assetUuid**
Asset have a `List<Stat>`
Now I want to add **stat** in a Asset of **assetList** if assetUuid match

```
    class Asset {
              List<Stat> stats =[]
              @Id
             String assetUuid
      }

class Stat { String assetUuid }
```

Suppose i have 10 Stats object and in which 2 stats object have same assetUuid. Now i want to get that 2 stats which have same assetUuid and make a list  and then set it to asset.stats = 2 stats object

Write now i am implemented in this way , is there is any other efficient way using java stream

```
assets.getContent().each { asset ->
    List<Stat> stats = []
    stats.each { stat ->
        if (stat.assetUUID == asset.uuid)
            stats.add(stat)
    }
    asset.stats = stats
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please add samples of both lists

Comment: and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert a list of `Asset` to a map
2. Iterate the list of `Stat` and add the stat to a matching asset.

Assuming that `Asset` has a method `addStat` implemented like this:

```java
// class Asset
List<Stat> stats;

public Asset addStat(Stat stat) {
    if (null == stats) {
        stats = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    stats.add(stat);
    return this;
}
```

it would be convenient to use `Map::computeIfPresent` as follows

```java
Map<AssetUuid, Asset> assetMap = assetList.stream() // Stream<Asset>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Asset::getUuid, asset -> asset, (a1, a2) -> a1));

stats.forEach(stat -> 
    assetMap.computeIfPresent(stat.getAssetUuid(), (k, v) -> v.addStat(stat))
);

// or like this using lambda
stats.forEach(stat ->
        assetMap.computeIfPresent(stat.getAssetUuid(), (k, v) -> { 
            v.getStats().add(stat); 
            return v;
        }) 
);
```

---

If the newly matched stats should overwrite those in `asset`, this can be implemented like this (assuming there's a setter `Asset::setStats`):

```java
Map<AssetUuid, List<Stat>> mapStats = stats.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Stat::getAssetUuid));

// overwrite only lists of stat only in matched assets
assetList.stream()
        .map(asset -> mapStats.containsKey(asset.getAssetUuid()))
        .forEach(asset -> asset.setStats(mapStats.get(asset.getAssetUuid())));

// overwrite lists of stat in all assets (non-matched with an empty list)
assetList.stream()
        .forEach(asset -> asset.setStats(mapStats.getOrDefault(
            asset.getAssetUuid(), Collections.emptyList()
        )));
```

Comment: I edited the question please go through it once

Comment: Initially you wrote _Now I want to add stat in a Asset of assetList if assetUuid match_, so it implies that matching stats are added to existing stats in the asset.  Do you need to _replace_ the existing stats with the newly matched ones?

Comment: Yes i need to replace the existing stats with the newly matched ones

Comment: and please upvote my question i edited the question

Comment: I am waiting for your response

Comment: @chaitanyagupta it seems we have been downvoted both :)